# If $\| \varphi\| = 1$, then $\varphi (B_E) = (-1,1).$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $E$ be a real normed space and $\varphi \in E'$, $\|\varphi\| = 1$. Is it true that
>   $\varphi (B_E) = (-1,1)$ ?

Clearly, if $x\in B_E$, we have $\varphi(x) \in (-1,1)$ since $|\varphi(x)| \leq \|x\|$. Hence $\varphi (B_E) \subset(-1,1)$.

I tried to prove $(-1,1) \subset \varphi (B_E)$ but it's not clear for me how to do it.

Comment: Is $B_E$ the open unit ball in $E$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remark that if $\|x\|=1$, $\phi(x)>0$  and $\mid c\mid \leq 1$,  $\phi(cx)=c\phi(x)\in (-\phi(x),\phi(x))$ conversely if $d\in (-\phi(x),\phi(x))$, $d=c\phi(x)=\phi(cx)$, $\mid c\mid\leq 1$. We have $\|cx\|\leq 1$ thus $(-\phi(x),\phi(x))\subset \phi(B_E)$.

Since $\|\phi\|=1$, for every $0<c<1$, there exists $x_c$ such that $\|x_c\|\leq 1$ and $\mid \phi(x_c)\mid\geq 1-c$. We can suppose $\phi(x_c)>0$ thus $(-(1-c),1-c)\subset (-\phi(x_c),\phi(x_c))\subset \phi(B_E)$. This implies that $(-1,1)\subset \phi(B_E)$.